# Word Search&Replace all Uppercase result

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

i want to replace some texts in the header area of my word file.
the actual replacement works, but it replaces all in Upper-case, no matter how the replacement text really looks like.
that's the code I use:

```
    og = ""
    vn = ""
    nn = ""
    tl = ""
    fx = ""
    getUserdatadata()

    Dim tags As String() = {"XCDATEX", "XORGANIX", "XNAMEX", "XTELEX", "XFAXX"}
    Dim name As String = vn + " " + nn
    Dim replaces As String() = {Today.ToShortDateString, og, name, tl, fx}
    worddoc.Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = WdViewType.wdPrintView
    worddoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekFirstPageHeader
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        With worddoc.Application.Selection.Find
            .Text = tags(i)
            .Replacement.Text = replaces(i)
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue
            .Execute(Replace:=WdReplace.wdReplaceOne)
        End With
    Next
```

for date, organisation, phone and fax there is no problem (organisation is fully in upper-case anyway).
But for the name, it always transforms the whole text to uppercase.
How to fix this?

Comment: even if I use something like "this should be lowercase" instead of replaces(i) the text gets convertet to uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found it:
I needed to add
 `.MatchCase = true`
to the with statement